# no attribute named read_csv in pandas python

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataset, attributeerror

I am new to machine learning and am creating a dataset using pandas in Python. I looked up a tutorial and was just trying out a basic code for creating a dataframe, but I keep getting the following trace-back:

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'read_csv'

I have saved the csv file in the csv(comma delimited) formatfrom Excel 13.
Here's my code:

```
    import pandas
    import csv

    mydata = pandas.read_csv('foo.csv')
    target = mydata["Label"]

    data = mydata.ix[:,:-1]
```

Comment: Likely in your cwd you have a file named `pandas.py` which is being imported instead of the pandas library.

Comment: There was! Pretty stupid mistake, but that didn't solve the problem though.

Comment: Also delete the `pandas.pyc` file there.

Comment: What has happened is that when the file is imported Python compiles it to bytecode and puts it in a `.pyc` file. In the future if a `.pyc` file is found Python will import that.

Comment: you can also try reload(pandas)

Comment: Thanks guys, things worked out.

Answer (score 5):

There was a file named `pandas.py` (and/or `pandas.pyc`) in the working directory, which was imported instead of the pandas library. Removing or renaming the file/s solved the problem.

Comment: I got the same error with a `csv.py` in my directory. Rename the file also solved the problem

Comment: I do not have any such files and yet I have the same error.

Comment: @HimabinduBoddupalli are you sure you are getting this exact `AttributeError`? Please make sure you do not have .py and .pyc files with the name 'pandas' in that folder. Another thing to try: right after `import pandas` try printing `pandas.__dict__.keys()` and check whether the list of objects there makes sense. `read_csv` should be listed of course.

Answer (score 0):

More likely you have not installed pandas correctly . For me installing pandas correctly got me through this error .
Here goes the installation .....

```
sudo apt-get install python-numpy cython
```

This will install a fast numeric processing library (numpy) and a tool required in the pandas build process (cython).

**Test numpy**

Open up a Python prompt by running the following:

```
python
```

At the prompt, type the following:

```
 >>> import numpy
 >>> print numpy.__version__
```

You should see a number like "1.6.1" or higher.

**Test cython**

Open up a Python prompt by running the following:

```
python
```

At the prompt, type the following (capitalization matters!):

```
 >>> import Cython
 >>> print Cython.__version__
```

You should see a number like "0.15.1" or higher.

**Download pandas**

We recommend storing pandas in a directory called ''projects'' in your user directory. To do that, run the following commands:

```
mkdir -p ~/projects
cd ~/projects
git clone https://github.com/pydata/pandas.git
cd pandas
```

You will see git download pandas. Once the download finishes, and you get your prompt back, proceed to the next step.

**Build pandas**

To build pandas, you have to run the following two commands:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

This will take about 2 minutes. Once it is finished, run this command:

```
python setup.py build
```

This will also take about 2 minutes.

**Test pandas**

To make sure it has built properly, run the following command inside the pandas directory:

```
python
```

Within this python prompt, type:

```
 >>> import pandas
 >>> print pandas.__version__
```

You should see this version number: '''0.10.0b1'''. 
Done hope this rids you off the error .