# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'read_csv'

Tags: python, pandas

Very similar question to this ([no attribute named read_csv in pandas python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31752715/no-attribute-named-read-csv-in-pandas-python)) but the solutions are not working for me.

Very simple code thats not working

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df.read_csv('flexibility user survey.csv')
```

I tried adding `reload(pd)` but that didn't help. No pandas.py or pyc in the working directory either

full error just in case it helps

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-5c55472122b4> in <module>()
     12 
     13 df = pd.DataFrame()
---> 14 df.read_csv('flexibility user survey.csv')

/Users/davidpier/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.pyc in __getattr__(self, name)
   1945                 return self[name]
   1946             raise AttributeError("'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" %
-> 1947                                  (type(self).__name__, name))
   1948 
   1949     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'read_csv'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('flexibility user survey.csv')
```

The error's right: `read_csv` isn't an attribute of a [`DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html).  It's a method of pandas itself: [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).  The difference between your question and [the other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31752715/no-attribute-named-read-csv-in-pandas-python) is that they're calling it properly (as `pandas.read_csv` or `pd.read_csv`) and you're calling it as if it were an attribute of your dataframe (as `df.read_csv`).

Comment: Thats the one! Obvious now that you point this out doh. 6 mins till i can mark this as the answer